# Angularjs input string to time format

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angular. I am working in uib time picker, it doesn't accept the string time.

For example, I have time from json like "06:00". I need 24hrs and 12hrs format also. The problem is I am creating the directive for display time in ng-model, and I have a text input also. Suppose if I enter the value in input text, example 1111, it is needed to be formatted to 11:11

Some other examples: 183 - 18:03 , 18349 - 18:34:09 like this.

Please some one help me to solve this problem.

```
dateTimeMask.directive('timeMask', function($filter) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    priority: 1,
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        var timeFormat;

        function formatter(value) {

            var formattedValueLength = timeFormat.length;
            var unformattedValueLength = timeFormat.replace(':', '').length;
            var timeMask = new String(timeFormat);

            if (ngModel.$isEmpty(value)) {
                return value;
            }
            if (!value) {
                ngModel.$setValidity('time', true);
                  return null;
                } else if (angular.isDate(value) && !isNaN(value)) {
                    ngModel.$setValidity('time', true);
                  return value;
                } 
            else if (angular.isString(value)) {
              var timeRegex = /^(0?[0-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9] ?[a|p]m$/i;
              if (!scope.showMeridian) {
                timeRegex = /^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/;
              }
              if (!timeRegex.test(value)) {
                  ngModel.$setValidity('time', false);
                  return undefined;
              }
              else {
                ngModel.$setValidity('time', true);
                var date = new Date();
                var sp = value.split(":");
                var apm = sp[1].match(/[a|p]m/i);
                if (apm) {
                  sp[1] = sp[1].replace(/[a|p]m/i, '');
                  if (apm[0].toLowerCase() == 'pm') {
                    sp[0] = sp[0] + 12;
                  }
                }
                date.setHours(sp[0], sp[1]);
                return date;
              }
            }
            else {
              ngModel.$setValidity('time', false);
              return undefined;
            }
        }

        var showTime = function(data) {
            timeFormat = (!scope.showMeridian) ? "HH:mm" : "hh:mm a";
            return $filter('date')(formatter(data), timeFormat);
          };

        scope.$watch('showMeridian', function(value) {
            var myTime = ngModel.$modelValue;
            if (myTime) {
                element.val(showTime(myTime));
            }

          });

        ngModel.$formatters.push(function (value) {
        timeFormat = (!scope.showMeridian) ? "HH:mm" : "hh:mm a";
          var date = formatter(value);
          return date;
        });

        ngModel.$parsers.push(function (value) {
          var date = showTime(value);
          return date;
        });


    } //link function
  };
});
```

Here is my html code which will display the time in pop up i need to update both text and popup values please some one to help me to solve this problem.

Comment: I don't know if you're just looking for a solution to your problem or if you just want to implement a solution yourself.

A quick solution would be to use angularjs built in input time directive:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btime%5D

Comment: Yes. but i tried time also it's shows ng-model must be a date object and also i can't able to remove the spinner in textbox